# foreach loop $_POST exclude empty fields and fields that are allready in database

Tags: php

I will try to explain the problem i have for the moment with a form, $_POST and insert it into an MYSQL database

this is my code:

```
$getadmrmaid        = $_GET['id'];

$admrmadetstmt  = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM rma_detail
            LEFT JOIN rma ON rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id
            LEFT JOIN klanten ON rma.r_klantid=klanten.k_id
            LEFT JOIN contactpersonen ON rma.r_contactid=contactpersonen.c_id
            WHERE rd_rma_nr = ?");
$admrmadetstmt->bindParam(1,$getadmrmaid);                      
$admrmadetstmt->execute();
$admrmadetrow = $admrmadetstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
         if (!empty($_POST[$key]) && $admrmadetrow[$key] !== $value){
$uprmadetstmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rma_detail SET $key = ? WHERE rd_id = $getadmrmaid");
$uprmadetstmt->bindParam(1, $value);
$uprmadetstmt->execute();
    }
    }
}
```

In words this is what i try to do:

I have a form that contains select and input fields. It represents a "Damaged parts" (RMA) tool that you can use to follow the damaged part and at additional information on the flow. For example today i fill in i have recieved the part "YES" and tomorrow i fill in i have send the part to my dealer "YES" so like an auto update every step. It is necessary that if a field is empty today that is doesn't include it into my update (inside the foreach) loop and if it is already filled in you cannot update it also. The code above isn't doing that i dont get any error but it also doesn't word and i cant seem to find where my problem is. Is there someone who could help me solving this issue? Maybe also provide me some tips regarding the coding how i could downsize it for example or make it cleaner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use '!==' insted of '!=' ? And why do you use '$key' in the update Query and not ' SET ? = ? WHERE '. And I woud not use 'if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')' but 'if(isset($_POST)){'... so what to do: add print_r($admrmadetrow) in the 'if' and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I dont understand what you mean about the column $key? As i remember it is not possible to use bindparam an a column name or am i wrong? I still have some problems with updating my MYSQL i got error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ' ' because he still wants to enter my empty fields to. Can i exclude these?